# Html transparent text input box

Tags: html, input, transparency, transparent

I have the following code example:

```css
<style>
{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.input {
 margin: 0;
 padding-top:0px;
 padding-bottom:0px;
 padding-left:0px;
 padding-right:0px;
 opacity: 0.6;
 filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
 background-color:#000;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
}
#input {
  opacity: 0.6;
 filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  }
.bgDiv {
 margin: 0;
 padding-top:0px;
 padding-bottom:0px;
 padding-left:0px;
 padding-right:0px;
 z-index:1;
}
.mainDiv {
 margin: 0;
 padding-top:0px;
 padding-bottom:0px;
 padding-left:0px;
 padding-right:0px;
 z-index:3;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="bgDiv" name="bgDiv" class="bgDiv">
<img src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/2u5OrmL.png" style="background-image: url('http://wallpapercave.com/wp/2u5OrmL.png'); -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;">
</div>
<div id="mainDiv" name="mainDiv" class="mainDiv">
<form id="iform" name="iform" action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" maxleth="18" align="center" id="input" name="input" class="input" placeholder="placeholder" style="border:0;outline:none;width:100%;height:100%;font-size:98px;text-align: center;" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
</form>
</div>
```

I am attempting to make the text input have a transparent background, so the user can see the underlying background image of the page. While at the same time, still be able to see text typed in the box.

```
input[type=text] {
background: transparent;
border: none;
```

}
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);

none of those seem to work or have any effect. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try with

```
            background-color: transparent;
```

```css
     input {
        background-color: transparent;

    }
    .WRAPPER {
        background-color: #000;
        height: 575px;
        width: 975px;
        background-image: url("http://wallpapercave.com/wp/2u5OrmL.png");
        top: auto;
        margin: -8px;
    }
    body {
        
        background-color: #000;
        background-image: url("http://wallpapercave.com/wp/2u5OrmL.png");
    }
    #email {
        background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        color:white;
        border: none;
        outline:none;
        height:30px;
        transition:height 1s;
        -webkit-transition:height 1s;
    }
    #email:focus {
      
        height:50px;
        font-size:16px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="bgDiv" name="bgDiv" class="bgDiv">
<img src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/2u5OrmL.png" style="background-image: url('http://wallpapercave.com/wp/2u5OrmL.png'); -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;">
</div>
<div id="mainDiv" name="mainDiv" class="mainDiv">
<form id="iform" name="iform" action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" maxleth="18" align="center" id="input" name="input" class="input" placeholder="placeholder" style="border:0;outline:none;width:100%;height:100%;font-size:98px;text-align: center;" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated my fidle to my actual code being used on page, kinda. I must be doing something wrong... Also, I know some of it like the .input and #input in css is redundant, I just left it to show I tried both ways.

Comment: The background image has to be from an <img> tag, not the actual body background. (For use with map areas later). Also, That makes the input box's text transparent as well.

Comment: Ill work with this, I think it may work now! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9vur45ea/1/) that gives an example.

Comment: Try that with a text input though, It doesnt work for me.

Comment: Works fine for me...updated the fiddle, try it again.

Comment: Updated my fidle to my actual code being used on page, kinda.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the thing that you want :

```css
body,html{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.wrapper{
  background: url('http://wallpapercave.com/wp/2u5OrmL.png');
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center
}
input{
  background: transparent;
  color: #FFF;
  top: 40vh;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <form id="iform" name="iform" action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" maxleth="18" align="center" id="input" name="input" class="input" placeholder="placeholder" style="width:90%;font-size:98px;text-align: center;" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If any of the above code doesn't work for you , then try this

```
<input type="text" name="name" style="background-color:transparent;" />
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For one of the websites I am working on, I was able to use transparent text in order to bring a button lower than it was initially supposed to be.

```
<div style="display:inline-block;user-select: none;opacity: 0;border:0.1px solid ;border-radius:1px;padding:1px;background:linear-gradient(to bottom,,)">Transparent Text</div>
```

This div style has no user select, and opacity. When viewed, for my website anyway is completely invisible as intended.

I hope this helps in some way! I know I am kinda late to the party.